# How to add a Add_button to first cardview on deleting second cardview from LinearLayout i.e. when number of children to be left in Linear Layout is?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, cardview

What i am trying to achieve is that when i click on `addRowBtn` (**+**) a new card view is added to the Linear Layout and the add button (**+**) of previous cardview is removed. The challenge i am facing is when i have 2 cards in Linear Layout and i delete then second cardView, i want to again add that add button (**+**) to the previous i.e. first cardView left in the Linear Layout.

Also, i have two buttons, `fromDateEditText` & `toDateEditText` for which i want to open datepicker but it opens for first cardView and not for dynamically added cardViews.

Please help me with this.

**ExperienceInfoActivity**

```
package kbg.com.kbgpos.forms;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import kbg.com.kbgpos.R;

public class ExperienceInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private LinearLayout parentRelativeLayout;
    private View v;
    EditText fromDateEditText,toDateEditText;
    private ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_experience_info);
        initViews();
        initListeners();
    }


    private void initViews() {
        toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarExperienceInfoActivity);
        toolbar.setTitle("Employee Experience Info");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolBarTitle));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        parentRelativeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.experienceDetailsInfoRelLayout);
        CardView experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw = findViewById(R.id.experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw);
        ImageView delRowBtn = findViewById(R.id.delRowBtn);
        ImageView addRowBtn = findViewById(R.id.addRowBtn);
        delRowBtn.setTag(experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw);
        addRowBtn.setTag(experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw);
        params = experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw.getLayoutParams();
        fromDateEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fromDateEditText);
        toDateEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.toDateEditText);
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        fromDateEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if(event.getRawX() >= fromDateEditText.getRight() - fromDateEditText.getTotalPaddingRight()) {
                        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                                  int dayOfMonth) {

                                int s=monthOfYear+1;
                                String a = dayOfMonth+"/"+s+"/"+year;
                                fromDateEditText.setText(""+a);
                            }
                        };

                        Time date = new Time();
                        DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(ExperienceInfoActivity.this, dpd, date.year ,date.month, date.monthDay);
                        d.show();

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        toDateEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if(event.getRawX() >= toDateEditText.getRight() - toDateEditText.getTotalPaddingRight()) {
                        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                                  int dayOfMonth) {

                                int s=monthOfYear+1;
                                String a = dayOfMonth+"/"+s+"/"+year;
                                toDateEditText.setText(""+a);
                            }
                        };

                        Time date = new Time();
                        DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(ExperienceInfoActivity.this, dpd, date.year ,date.month, date.monthDay);
                        d.show();

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void onAddField(View view) {
        try{

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.experience_details_row, null);
            if(parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount()>1){
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                parent.removeView(view);
            }
            ImageView delRowBtn = rowView.findViewById(R.id.delRowBtn);
            delRowBtn.setTag(rowView);
            ImageView addRowBtn=rowView.findViewById(R.id.addRowBtn);
            addRowBtn.setTag(rowView);
            rowView.setLayoutParams(params);
            parentRelativeLayout.addView(rowView, parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount());
            EditText employerNameEditText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.employerNameEditText);
            employerNameEditText.requestFocus();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void onDelete(View v) {
        try{
            if(parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount()>2) {
                CardView cv = (CardView) ((ImageView) v).getTag();
                parentRelativeLayout.removeView(cv);
            }else{
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
                v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_grey_50));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_experience_info**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".forms.ExperienceInfoActivity">

    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarExperienceInfoActivity"></include>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/personalDetailScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbarExperienceInfoActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/experienceDetailsInfoRelLayout"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/experienceInfoActivityFormHeadingCardVw"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Experience Details"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
                card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/employerNameTextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/employerNameEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:hint="Employer Name" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/designationTextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                        android:layout_below="@id/employerNameTextInputLayout">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/designationEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:hint="Designation" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/addressTextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                        android:layout_below="@id/designationTextInputLayout">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/addressEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:hint="Address" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/fromDateTextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                        android:layout_below="@id/addressTextInputLayout">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/fromDateEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:inputType="date"
                            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_perm_contact_calendar_black_24dp"
                            android:drawableTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                            android:hint="From Date" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/toDateTextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                        android:layout_below="@id/fromDateTextInputLayout">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/toDateEditText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:inputType="date"
                            android:hint="To Date"
                            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_perm_contact_calendar_black_24dp"
                            android:drawableTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/addDelLayout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_below="@id/toDateTextInputLayout">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/addRowBtn"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:onClick="onAddField"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/delRowBtn"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:onClick="onDelete"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="CANCEL"
            android:background="#e0e0e0"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="SUBMIT"
            android:background="#ffe57f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**experience_details_row**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/experienceInfoActivityFormCardVw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/employerNameTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/employerNameEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:hint="Employer Name" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/designationTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                android:layout_below="@id/employerNameTextInputLayout">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/designationEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:hint="Designation" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/addressTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                android:layout_below="@id/designationTextInputLayout">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/addressEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:hint="Address" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/fromDateTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                android:layout_below="@id/addressTextInputLayout">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fromDateEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_perm_contact_calendar_black_24dp"
                    android:drawableTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                    android:hint="From Date" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/toDateTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
                android:layout_below="@id/fromDateTextInputLayout">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/toDateEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:hint="To Date"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_perm_contact_calendar_black_24dp"
                    android:drawableTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/addDelLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@id/toDateTextInputLayout">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/addRowBtn"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:onClick="onAddField"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/delRowBtn"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:onClick="onDelete"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have attached the images too:
[image]

[image]

The images shown depicts two states: on adding 2nd card and on deleting second card.

Comment: If i can understand your problem you want set button on the last item of the list the you just need to set the button on the onclick listener of the add button and delete button this might solve your prob

Comment: First of all I prefer you to manage that code in `RecyclerView`. If you want a quick solution create `List<View> cardViews` and where you inflate the views add it to list and on delete get the View the respected view from list and handle the way you want.

Comment: and there is some logical issue in your design.. as you are having delete buttons in all of your CardViews what if user deleted a random CardView from not the one at the last for example second last? are you adding the add button to the 3rd last row in that case...?

Comment: @FaisalNaseer : in answer to your second comment, yes i'll add the button to 3rd last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disclaimer: this is not the best way to code such layout use
>   RecyclerView.

You can use getChildAt(index) to get the child at particular index inside parent layout.

```
public void onAddField(View view) {
 /* first make add button invisible on which click operation is performed
 */
 view.getVisibility(View.GONE);

try{

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.experience_details_row, null);

            //get reference to buttons here form inflated view
            EditText fromDateEditTextDynamic=(EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.fromDateEditText);
            EditText toDateEditTextDynamic=(EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.toDateEditText);
            //apply listeners
            fromDateEditTextDynamic.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if(event.getRawX() >= fromDateEditTextDynamic.getRight() - fromDateEditTextDynamic.getTotalPaddingRight()) {
                        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                                  int dayOfMonth) {

                                int s=monthOfYear+1;
                                String a = dayOfMonth+"/"+s+"/"+year;
                                fromDateEditTextDynamic.setText(""+a);
                            }
                        };

                        Time date = new Time();
                        DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(ExperienceInfoActivity.this, dpd, date.year ,date.month, date.monthDay);
                        d.show();

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        toDateEditTextDynamic.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if(event.getRawX() >= toDateEditTextDynamic.getRight() - toDateEditTextDynamic.getTotalPaddingRight()) {
                        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                                  int dayOfMonth) {

                                int s=monthOfYear+1;
                                String a = dayOfMonth+"/"+s+"/"+year;
                                toDateEditTextDynamic.setText(""+a);
                            }
                        };

                        Time date = new Time();
                        DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(ExperienceInfoActivity.this, dpd, date.year ,date.month, date.monthDay);
                        d.show();

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });



            ImageView delRowBtn = rowView.findViewById(R.id.delRowBtn);
            delRowBtn.setTag(rowView);
            ImageView addRowBtn=rowView.findViewById(R.id.addRowBtn);
            addRowBtn.setTag(rowView);
            rowView.setLayoutParams(params);
            parentRelativeLayout.addView(rowView, parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount());
            EditText employerNameEditText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.employerNameEditText);
            employerNameEditText.requestFocus();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


   }
```

then replace your these lines in your code

```
try{
            if(parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount()>2) {
                CardView cv = (CardView) ((ImageView) v).getTag();
                parentRelativeLayout.removeView(cv);
            }else{
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
                v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_grey_50));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

with the code below it will make addbtn visible for every previously added CardView.

```
try{
    if(parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount()>2) {
                int indexPreviousCardView = parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount()-2;
                if(indexPreviousCardView > -1){
                    CardView previousCardView = parentRelativeLayout.getChildAt(indexPreviousCardView);
                    //now get the addBtn from previous cardView and set its visibility 
                    // as it was gone as we added new row so set its visibility to visible
                    ImageView addBtn = (ImageView) previousCardView.findViewById(R.id.addRowBtn);
                    addBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            CardView cv = (CardView) ((ImageView) v).getTag();
            parentRelativeLayout.removeView(cv);
            }
            else{
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
                v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_grey_50));
            }
}catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Please specify as how can i use your code snipped to add the addRow btn?

Comment: to hide the addRow button for previous row in  `onAddField(View view)` i have used `if(parentRelativeLayout.getChildCount()>1){
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                parent.removeView(view);
            }`

Comment: pardon me for that i think its better to hide it instead of removing

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. Could you please answer my 2nd question that was mentioned in the post too i.e. **Also, i have two buttons, fromDateEditText & toDateEditText for which i want to open datepicker but it opens for first cardView and not for dynamically added cardViews.** ?

Comment: Waiting for your reply :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178352/discussion-between-faisal-naseer-and-jeevika-dhillon).

Comment: I am really grateful to you. May God bless you. Thanks :) If in future i ask you for some doubts please entertain them!! Thanks again !!

Comment: Now i want to load some data (only if available) from database into these dynamically generated cards so, how can i handle this in onPostExecute method to set data and generate cards having that data?